# Why doesn't "between (char '"') (char '"') (many charLiteral)" work for parsing string literals?

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, megaparsec

The documentation for `Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer.charLiteral` suggests using `char '"' *> manyTill charLiteral (char '"')` for parsing string literals (where `manyTill` is defined in the module `Control.Applicative.Combinators` in the `parser-combinators` library).

However, `Control.Applicative.Combinators` also defines `between`, which -- as far as I can see -- should do the same as the above suggestion when used like so: `between (char '"') (char '"') (many charLiteral)`.

However, using the `between` parser above does not work for parsing string literals -- failing with "*unexpected end of input.
expecting '"' or literal character*" (indicating that the ending quote is never detected). Why not?

Also, more generally, why isn't `between pBegin pEnd (many p)` equivalent to `pBegin *> manyTill p pEnd`?

Comment: Because checking against a parser takes time?

Comment: Side note: this would probably work fine in parsers that backtrack by default, which is basically all of them other than (mega)parsec.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica no, I don't think backtracking can help you here. That would be if `charLiteral` actually failed on `"` (but did still consume the character, so control wouldn't be given back to what comes after the `many`). But in this case, `many charLiteral` actually succeeds – it successfully consumes _all the input_. — Anyway, megaparsec _does_ auto-backtrack on simple chars and strings, just not on bigger combinators.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Upon testing, it looks like this is more subtle than either of us thought. It works as I expected [with `regex-applicative`](https://pastebin.com/igC6NHB1) and [with `ReadP`](https://pastebin.com/ihjZsTAX) but fails as you expected [with `attoparsec`](https://pastebin.com/wkYrigQF). I'm confused because I thought `attoparsec` did backtrack like those others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`between l r m` doesn't do anything spectacular, it really just tries `l` then `m` then `r` and gives back the result of `m`. So, in `between (char '"') (char '"') (many charLiteral)`, the `many charLiteral` doesn't know it's not supposed to consume the `"`. The `many` just keeps consuming whatever its argument parser accepts... which, because `charLiteral` just accepts *anything*, means it churns right through everything until the end of the input. The second `char '"'` has no way of stopping this, it just needs to make do with what's left... i.e., *fail* because there *is* nothing left!

By contrast, `manyTill` actually checks whether the “till”, matches, and *only* applies each iteration of the content parser when it doesn't. Therefore, the terminating `"` is not passed to `charLiteral`, and you get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be correct to sum it up by saying that `between l r (many p)` and `l *> manyTill p r` are equivalent iff `p` does not consume what `r` consumes?

Comment: I think yes, but after Joseph's comments I'm not so sure anymore I understand what's going on.